# How to Preserve the Validity of Django Template Code in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup

I am trying to operate on some Django templates using Beautiful Soup. In some cases, when I put html that contains Django code through a `BeautifulSoup` instance, soup outputs invalid Django code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

django_string = '<a href="{% url "some_url" %}">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(django_string, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
<a %}"="" href="{% url " some_url"="">
# expected <a href="{% url "some_url" %}">
```

I also tried using the `html5lib` and `lxml` parsers. The `lxml` parser's output is slightly different than above, but still invalid.

Is there any way use Beautiful Soup to output valid Django template code, or have I reached the limits of what it is designed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two sets of double quotes in there, which is why BeautifulSoup thinks your string should be split up into multiple attributes. Try using single quotes inside the Django part:

```
django_string = '<a href="{% url \'some_url\' %}">'
```